# How can I set AnimationCurve by script?

Tags: unity, c#

In the top of the script:

```
public AnimationCurve curve;
```

Then the object in the editor have AnimationCurve but without any curve yet:

[image: Animationcurve]

I want to set one of the curves via the script in the Start.

For example to select this one the most one in the right:

[image: AnimationCurve]

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs on [AnimationCurve](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html), including the [use of its constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve-ctor.html) and creating [Keyframes](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Keyframe.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In top of script:

```
public AnimationCurve curve;
```

In Start:

```
public void Start()
    {
      if(curve == null)
        {
          curve = new AnimationCurve(new Keyframe(0, 0), new Keyframe(1, 1));
        }
        curve.preWrapMode = WrapMode.Clamp;
        curve.postWrapMode = WrapMode.Clamp;
    }
```

Comment: You might want to first check whether the curve is null / empty before replacing it. One of the advantages of a public variable in a MonoBehaviour is that it allows a developer to customize the initial values inside the Unity editor's inspector, if they want custom behaviour on a particular instance. So you can preserve that capability by not stomping the curve if someone's already provided a custom one.